# NFS volume created manually mounts but shows empty contents

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

server: `docker ubuntu, 18.06.3-ce`
local : `docker for mac, 19.03.13`

I have created a volume in the swarm manually, to a remote nfs server.  When I try to mount this volume in a service it appears to work, but the contents are empty and any writes *seem* to succeed (calling code doesn't crash), but the bytes are gone.  Maybe even to /dev/null.

When I declare a similar volume inside the compose file it works.  The only difference I can find is the label "com.docker.stack.namespace".

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=10.0.1.100 \
    --opt device=:/data/ \
    my_nfs
```

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  my-api:
    volumes:
      - "compose_nfs:/data1/"  # works fine
      - "externl_nfs:/data2/"  # empty contents, forgotten writes

volumes:
  externl_nfs: 
    external: true
  compose_nfs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
      type: nfs
      o: addr=10.0.1.100
      device: ":/data/"
```

When inspecting the networks they are identical, except for that label.

```
{
    "CreatedAt": "2020-20-20T20:20:20Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {
        # label missing on the manually created one
        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "stackie"
    },
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/externl_nfs/_data",
    "Name": "compose_nfs",
    "Options": {
        "device": ":/data/",
        "o": "addr=10.0.1.100",
        "type": "nfs"
    },
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

Comment: Does the volume exist on the same node where the task was scheduled? Show the output of `docker volume inspect externl_nfs` on that node.

Comment: Damn good point.  The volumes exist on all hosts where a container references them, but i had only done `inspect` on the manager.  On the workers the "options" node is NULL!  `{ "Driver": "local", "Name": "some_other_nfs", "Options": null, "Scope": "local", ...}`

Comment: I've created a new volume and used a dummy container to test it, and its certainly repeatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an external volume, swarm is deferring the creation of that volume to you. Volumes are also local to the node they are created on, so you must create that volume on every node where swarm could schedule this job. For this reason, many will delegate the volume creation to swarm mode itself and put the definition in the compose file. So in your example, before scheduling the service, *on each node* run:

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=10.0.1.100 \
    --opt device=:/data/ \
    external_nfs
```

Otherwise, when the service gets scheduled on a node without the volume defined, it appears that swarm will create the container, and that create command generates a default named volume, storing the contents on that local node (I could also see swarm failing to schedule the service because of a missing volume, but your example shows otherwise).

Comment: Thank you for your help!  So swarm doesn't fail if an external volume isn't present, it just creates one of some kind with that name.  Rather different than I expected.  And it half-works :D  Maybe that "no crash" situation fixed on a newer version.  Because of this I've moved off volumes like this, and every stack.yml redeclares an identical nsf volume.  Sucks to keep in sync and double check, but it works :) It would be nice if swarm had a way to  manage volumes across the cluster, but I suppose there are quite logical issues with that.

Comment: Also, the line "many will delegate the volume creation to swarm" makes sense on the 3rd reading to me, rather than right away to an expert like yourself.  I'm not sure how to put it better though, maybe "most will put the definition in the compose file, but if you want to do it yourself you need to create it on each node manually".  :shrug:  Thanks again, its nice to have this explained so well!

Answer (score 0):

Answering this, since it is an older version of docker and probably not relevant to most people, considering the NFS part.

It appears to be a bug of some sort in docker/swarm.

1. Create a NFS volume on the swarm (via api, from remote)
2. Volume is correct on the manager node which was contacted
3. Volume is missing the `options` on all other worker nodes

As some strange side effect, the volume seems to work.  It can be mounted, writes succeed without issue, but all bytes written disappear.  Reads work but every file is "not found", which is logical considering the writes disappearing.

On manager:

```
> docker network inspect external_nfs
[{
    "CreatedAt": "2020-11-03T15:56:44+01:00",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {},
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/externl_nfs/_data",
    "Name": "externl_nfs",
    "Options": {
        "device": ":/data/",
        "o": "addr=10.0.1.100",
        "type": "nfs"
    },
    "Scope": "local"
}]
```

On worker:

```
> docker network inspect external_nfs
[{
    "CreatedAt": "2020-11-03T16:22:16+01:00",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {},
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/externl_nfs/_data",
    "Name": "externl_nfs",
    "Options": null,
    "Scope": "local"
}]
```

Comment: That looks like the volume created by swarm, I thought the question was asking about using the external defined volumes?

Comment: You are right!  I posted the question. I just copied the output from before, without paying attention.  I've edited it to reflect what it actually looks like (I still have one hanging around, thankfully)

Comment: It doesn't look like you created the external volume on the worker with NFS options in updated output. It's also confusing how the timestamps are identical, did you create these volumes with a script? Keep in mind an external volume isn't created by swarm mode or compose, so this is going to be an issue with how you created the volume on that worker.

Comment: Again, this is just an example.  I put in fake dates, I thought the repeated `20` would help out.  Also, the  name isn't really "external_nfs", if that helps, but rather a product specific name.  I use `docker volume create ...` when connected to that swarm remotely.  The volume should show up wherever a worker references it, and it does (happens to be all nodes).

Comment: To help out, I've put in the actual date, and also verified that the rest of the contents (outside name) are identical.  Also, the IP isn't the real one (but in the same general range).  Note, the difference in dates is between network creation and stack deployment times.